# How to get Transaction Action Etherscan

Tags: etherscan, web3.py, python, pyethereum

I'm trying to get **Transaction Action information** from [Etherscan Apis](https://etherscan.io/apis#proxy) by using a transaction hash without success.
Here is what I want to extract **(Swap 1 Ether For 2 Yf-DAI)** with the API.
I have already tried to decode information returned by

```
eth_getTransactionByHash
```

[Here](https://etherscan.io/apis#proxy) but nothing close to getting transaction action.
My question is which endpoint should I query or what do I do to get the transaction Action

Answer (score 2):

I asked Etherscan support and got the answer.

> We unfortunately do not have an endpoint that returns the "Transaction Action" information at this point of time.

> It is a popular one by request, and we will definitely consider to add it in a future update.

btw API Pro doc is located at https://etherscan.io/apidocs#APIpro
, I checked it as well, there is no such endpoint to get Transaction Actions for now.

You could workaround this by fetching transaction details page and parse it with BeautifulSoup if you really need it.

Comment: i wonder how etherscan derives it from the blocks. like its gotta be replicable somehow right?

Comment: I have no idea how Etherscan did it, don't know much about cryptocurrency stuff. didn't find alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what is needed is available in the API PRO plan:

"*Get Token Info by ContractAddress*" from https://etherscan.io/apis#APIpro

```
{
  "status": "1",
  "message": "OK",
  "result": [
    {
      "contractAddress": "0x...",
      "tokenName": "Token Name",
      "symbol": "Token Symbol",
      "divisor": "18",
      "tokenType": "ERC20",
      "totalSupply": "1000000000000000",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is to retrieve the hash, and look up transaction by hash and it will give you details. Slow though as every hash in transactions needs to be looked up.